# VueJS error : "Cannot read property of null" when I get items in the local storage

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, vuetify.js

I create an app with vue js (v2) and vuetify where `SidebarComponent` is a child of my root `AppComponent`.

To beginning in my AppComponent `created` hook I request backend API to get current user datas infos and
I set them in the local storage.

Then in the child `SidebarComponent` I want to get the current user datas from `local storage` but an error occurs at first run of the app which says data doesn't exist in. But in Chrome Dev Tools I well see the data. When I refresh the page the data are well recognized.

Anyone have a solution?

**AppComponent** :

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <side-bar/>
        <Header/>
        <Main/>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
    import SideBar from "@/components/layouts/SideBar";
    import Header from "@/components/layouts/Header";
    import Main from "@/components/layouts/Main";

    import axios from "axios";

    export default {
        name: 'App',
        components: {
            SideBar,
            Header,
            Main
        },
        beforeMount() {
            console.log('app')
            this.getRole()
            this.getEtats()
        },
        methods: {
            getRole() {
                axios.get('/role')
                    .then(response => {
                        let agent = {}
                        agent.role = response.data.data.role
                        agent.username = response.data.data.username
                        localStorage.setItem('badge.agent', JSON.stringify(agent))
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            },
            getEtats() {
                axios.get('/etats')
                    .then(response => {
                        localStorage.setItem('badge.etats', JSON.stringify(response.data.data))
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**SidebarComponent** :

```
<template>
    <v-navigation-drawer
            color="#f1ebeb"
            permanent
            app
            :expand-on-hover="$vuetify.breakpoint.xs || $vuetify.breakpoint.sm"
    >
        <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title class="title">
                    {{ username }}
                </v-list-item-title>
                <v-list-item-subtitle>
                    {{ userRole() }}
                </v-list-item-subtitle>
            </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-list>
            <v-list-item
                    v-for="([icon, text, to], i) in menuLabel()"
                    :key="i"
                    :to=to
            >
                <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>{{ icon }}</v-icon>
                </v-list-item-icon>

                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>{{ text }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "SideBar",
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },
        computed: {
            username() {
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('badge.agent')).username
            },
        },
        methods: {
            userRole() {
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('badge.agent')).role
            },
            menuLabel() {
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('badge.etats'))
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Errors :**

```
Cannot read property 'username' of null"

found in

---> <SideBar> at src/components/layouts/SideBar.vue
       <VApp>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>

Cannot read property 'role' of null"

found in

---> <Header> at src/components/layouts/Header.vue
       <VApp>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

Comment: Please provide some code showing where you're making the request and the error you're getting.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I added the code